# Issue of submitting form

Tags: php, javascript

Have a form like:

```
 <form name="myform" action="All.php" method="get">
 <input type='text' id='tx' name='tx' value=''>
 <td height="8" align="right" valign="middle"><a href="javascript: submitform('All')">All Cities</a> | <a href="javascript: submitform('Newyork')">Newyork</a> | <a href="javascript: submitform('Police')">Police</a></td></form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform(val)
{
$("#tx").val(val);
document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
```

And in All.php:

```
 <form method="get" action="index1.php" id="frm1">
 <select id="category" onchange="showSelected1();" style="width:150px">
 <option></option>
 <option value="1" <?php if($_GET["categoryText"] == "Marriages") echo "selected"; ?> >Marriages</option>
 <option value="2" <?php if($_GET["categoryText"] == "Birthdays") echo "selected"; ?> >Birthdays</option></select>
 <input type="hidden" id="categoryText" name="categoryText" value='<?= $_GET['categoryText']; ?>'/>

<select id="city" onchange="showSelected();" style="width:150px">
<option><?= $_GET['tx']; ?></option>
<option></option>
<option value="1" <?php if($_GET["cityText"] == "Newyork") echo "selected"; ?> >Newyork</option>
<option value="2" <?php if($_GET["cityText"] == "Police") echo "selected"; ?> >Police</option></select>
<input type="hidden" id="cityText" name="cityText" value='<?= $_GET['cityText']; ?>'/>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="formSubmit()"/></form>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function showSelected()
{
var selObj = document.getElementById('city');
var cityTextObj = document.getElementById('cityText');

var selIndex = selObj.selectedIndex;
cityTextObj.value = selObj.options[selIndex].text;
}
//-->
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function showSelected1()
{
var selObj = document.getElementById('category');
var categoryTextObj = document.getElementById('categoryText');

var selIndex = selObj.selectedIndex;
categoryTextObj.value = selObj.options[selIndex].text;

}
//-->
</script>
```

Means, from first page contents filling into a form itself in All.php. If somebody clicks submit button without changing the selection city, in All.php, its not showing and not taking the city value to index1.php.  Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
document.getElementById("myform").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have write wrong variable name into your below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform(val)
{
$("#hx").val(val);
document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
```

your have used hx insted of tx, so your code may be like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform(val)
{
$("#tx").val(val);
document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
```

change this and try your code again.

I have seen many other problems into your code , learn how to use single quote (') and double quote("). You have written this

```
value='<?= $_GET['categoryText']; ?>'  which is wrong.
```

correct way is `value='<?php $_GET["categoryText"]; ?>'`

Update you code according to this and run it again and come back here if there any problem.

Comment: OK...I am corrected that. The issue still persists. Selecting 'categoryText' and 'cityText', given submit, it will go to index1.php. Without changing any text hitting submit in 'index1.php' its not submitting the form.

Comment: Is this the problem of "echo selected"?